# How to finish the bar with rests

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, engraving, rests

Can you help me check these two bars?

[image: Two bars in common time. The first has: an eighth note beamed to a dotted eighth note, sixteenth rest, eighth rest, half rest. The second has: a dotted eighth note beamed to an eighth note, sixteenth rest, eighth rest, half rest.]

Did I finish these bars with rests correctly? Or haven't I handled these dotted eighth notes correctly?

Comment: Your rests are fine, but your written notes are a bit uncomfortable to read.  It would be easier to read if you put quaver, quaver tied to a semiquaver for the first example, and then dotted quaver, semiquaver tied to a semiquaver for the second example.

Comment: Is this for a rhythm quiz? Tying to only the first sixteenth of beat one seems kind of odd.

Comment: Nope. I've just learnt music theory. These rhythm were created randomly and I ask whether it's proper or not.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is on the money (BTW quaver = 8th note, semiquaver = 16th note). His or her advice is based on sight readers wanting to clearly see the beginning of every beat (in this case beat 2 of each bar) when 16th notes are involved. You can also substitute a single dotted 8th rest for the 16th and 8th note rests if you like.